# Structure of Enterprise Web Application using JSF

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, architecture, web

I'm developing enterprise web application which is using JSF with Eclipse IDE. But i'n not experienced at JSF web application architect, just not familiar with name classes ,projects,packages,web pages, template pages etc.. , is it possible to name packages like following:
CompanyName.systemName.controller (there would be controllers in it )
CompanyName.systemName.Model (there would be managed beans and other things in it )

even how to choose best structure for my project(mean Architecture of folders,classes,packages,web pages, template pages etc). if anyone has an idea ? i'd be glad if have sample project.

thanks

Comment: I've found http://horstmann.com/corejsf/ to be a valuable resource for JSF programming.  There is a mindset to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Those are fine package names. Some people like to group packages by purpose:

```
org.mycompany.myapp.controller
org.mycompany.myapp.dao
org.mycompany.myapp.service
etc...
```

For larger applications, I like to group them by feature:

```
org.mycompany.myapp.billing
org.mycompany.myapp.signup
org.mycompany.myapp.webservices
etc...
```

As for folder structure, a good Maven archetype can be very helpful. Here's a web page that gives a good walkthrough of setting up a few types of JSF projects using Maven archetypes: http://www.javaserverfaces.org/get-started

Answer (score 0):

If you look from architecture point of view, your JSF application should mirror very much like any other well architected Java-Web application.

For packaging I like to break first by functionality (like core, gui) and then by business unit level.

Something like:

```
com.comp.core.db.beans
com.comp.extension.ui.extension //If my application is going to give extension point for others to implement, extend the functionality.
com.comp.core.ui.controller
```

On a similar note pages, config files can be broken into separate logical units.